# Weird segfaults when calling TTF_OpenFont

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, codeblocks, sdl-2

I ported a game I am making from SDL 1.2 to SDL2. After porting the game and getting it to compile properly I get a segfault when I call TTF_OpenFont here:

```
bool cargararchivos(SDL_Texture* &background,SDL_Texture* &player,TTF_Font* &font,SDL_Texture* &bullet,Config* placlips,SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    string playerss;
    //Open the font
    font = TTF_OpenFont( "lazy.ttf", 28 );
    //If there was an error in loading the font
    if(font==NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    try{
        playerss = placlips->lookup("filename").c_str();
    }catch(const SettingNotFoundException &nfex)
    {
        cerr << "No 'name' setting in configuration file." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    //Open background
    background = cargarimagen("fondo.png",renderer);
    if(background==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    //Open player sprites
    player = cargarimagen(playerss,renderer);
    if(player==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    bullet = cargarimagen("bullet.png",renderer);
    if(bullet==NULL)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The segfault happens before TTF_OpenFont ends. The backtrace I get is:

```
#0 ??   ?? () (??:??)
#1 0x7ffff7410ce5   TTF_CloseFont(font=0x8af1e0) (SDL_ttf.c:933)
#2 0x7ffff74110fd   TTF_OpenFontIndexRW(src=<optimized out>, freesrc=<optimized out>, ptsize=<optimized out>, index=0) (SDL_ttf.c:489)
#3 0x409c9d cargararchivos(background=@0x7fffffffe598: 0x0, player=@0x7fffffffe590: 0x0, font=@0x7fffffffe580: 0x0, bullet=@0x7fffffffe588: 0x0, placlips=0x7fffffffe560, renderer=0x9c25b0) (/home/xxxxx/xxxxx/main.cpp:33)
#4 0x40a526 main(argc=1, args=0x7fffffffe6e8) (/home/xxxxx/xxxxx/main.cpp:173)
```

If I take out all the SDL_ttf stuff out I still get a similar segfault but with IMG_Load. I suspect it is an issue with my CodeBlocks setup because I can buiid the Lazy Foo SDL2 tutorials fine with g++ and run them.  Or maybe it is a bug? I am using Debian sid (Linux) by the way. Please help.

Comment: Have you updated or rebuilt SDL_ttf and SDL_img libraries to use SDL 2?

Comment: Could be heap corruption (which is approximately the worst problem to debug), if you're unlucky.

Comment: Joachim: yes, I did update SDL_ttf and SDL_img libraries. Though it is installed alongside the 1.2 libraries, maybe that is the issue, though I didn't have an issue with g++, only with Codeblocks.

Comment: codeblocks don't have a compiler; it uses something else, like gcc or clang. Check compilation and linking line. It is likely you're linking with 1.2 versions of SDL_image and SDL_ttf.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## D'oh!

There was an include to the 1.2 version of SDL_ttf that I forgot to change to the new version. Man, I am stupid. Thanks keltar!